# Advanced filter not working

Tags: excel, filter

I'm trying to filter a column based on values in another column. I click on the column that I want to filter (I click on "A" in sheet 1). The whole column is selected. I click on advanced filter. I click the button to select the second column. I go to sheet 2 and click on "A". That's my column with the filter criteria. I click OK and nothing happens. All records are returned. How the heck does that thing work?

**EDIT**

I finally found out why. The column that you use as filter criteria has to have the same header name as the column that you want to filter ... that's so stupid -_- why wouldn't you allow someone to filter a column based on a simple list of values without header name?

Comment: Can you share example data and expected output?

Comment: you can generate an example in 3 seconds: open excel, go to sheet 1 and enter "hello", "1", "2", "3" into the first 4 rows. then go to sheet 2 and enter "1", "2" into the first 2 rows. Now try to use advanced filter to filter the column in sheet 1 based on the column in sheet 2. It won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter based on a column `B` that will have formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A2)
```

Now just filter column `B` all values that are greater than 0.

As for your issue with `advanced filter` just select data without header row when applying advanced filter.

Comment: thank you zipa, I will test that but do you know why the advanced filter button doesn't work as you would intuitively expect it to?

Comment: that formula doesn't work because I do not want to count values. I need the values themselves!

Comment: It doesn't work because you `filter by` column doesn't have same header as the column you want to filter. More info [here](http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html)

Comment: oh I just edited my initial post. yes, that's the answer!

Comment: Your solution is brilliant and with it I fixed a similar issue as the OP. BTW, I still wasn't able to fix if to go with the 'Advanced Filter' route  - I already tried to make the two columns (in different sheets) to have the same heading name - but how do you define a 'heading name' in Excel? They can in different **rows**, right?